# Use function SetTextJustification (API)

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to use the `SetTextJustification` function, but it does not work as expected.

If I set the argument value of nBreakExtra to 40 or to 10 the output is the same, why is this?

Here is my code:

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          IntPtr hdc = richTextBox1.CreateGraphics().GetHdc();
          string str = "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff";
          SetTextJustification(hdc, 40, 5);
          TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, str, str.Length);
          SetTextJustification(hdc, 10, 5);
          TextOut(hdc, 20, 50, str, str.Length);
      }

      [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
      static extern bool SetTextJustification(IntPtr hdc, int nBreakExtra, int nBreakCount);

      [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
      static extern bool TextOut(IntPtr hdc, int nXStart, int nYStart, string lpString, int cbString);
```

the output is displayed as:
[image]

Comment: You merely splattered some pixels on the window owned by the RichTextBox control. They won't live for long, the RTB will repaint itself sooner or later and will redraw the text the way it thinks it should be drawn.  Which will not be justified, it doesn't support that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work ok.  Here is a screen shot of my test:

[image: Test form showing the results of the code]

I am not sure why your results are different.

Perhaps I could offer this as an alternative solution:
I have writen my own justification method:

```
public void PaintTextJustification(Graphics g, string text, Font font, PointF location, int lineWidth, bool applyToLastLine)
{
  string[] words = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  int wordCount = 0;
  float locY = location.Y;

  while (wordCount < words.Length)
  {
    StringBuilder rawLine = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> lineParts = new List<string>();

    while ((wordCount < words.Length) && (g.MeasureString(rawLine.ToString() + words[wordCount], font).Width < (float)lineWidth))
    {
      rawLine.Append(words[wordCount] + " ");
      lineParts.Add(words[wordCount] + " ");
      wordCount++;
    }
    string rawLineStr = rawLine.ToString().Trim();

    float padding = 0;
    if ((wordCount < words.Length) || (applyToLastLine))
    {
      // Only apply padding if not the last line.
      padding = ((float)lineWidth - g.MeasureString(rawLineStr, font).Width) / (lineParts.Count - 1);
    }

    float locX = location.X;
    foreach (string word in lineParts)
    {
      g.DrawString(word, font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(locX, locY));
      locX += g.MeasureString(word, font).Width + padding;
    }

    locY += g.MeasureString(rawLineStr, font).Height;
  }
}
```

Using this new method lets you choose the font and specify the total length of the line, it also allows you greater flexibility and customization (e.g. incoporating a flag that indicates if the last line should be justified or not).  You could also customize the method further by including the font color as a method argument.

This method can now be used as shown in the button event method below (note the first bit of this event handler method includes the code for testing the origonal solution):

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IntPtr hdc = richTextBox1.CreateGraphics().GetHdc();
  string str = "aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff";

  SetTextJustification(hdc, 40, 5);
  TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, str, str.Length);

  SetTextJustification(hdc, 10, 5);
  TextOut(hdc, 20, 40, str, str.Length);

  // Another Approach:
  Graphics g = richTextBox1.CreateGraphics();
  PaintTextJustification(g, str, richTextBox1.Font, new PointF(20f, 90f), 220, true);

  System.Drawing.Font newFont = new Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Bold);
  string longStr = "This is a very long string which will need to be split across several lines when it is justified.";
  PaintTextJustification(g, longStr, newFont, new PointF(20f, 110f), 220, false);
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the results that show both approaches:

[image]

Anyway I hope this helps.

Comment: Look at my edit to the question, there are two drawings, in the first  the break extra determined on 40 and in the second on 10, and their output is equal.

Comment: @user1544067 you will need to provide some more information regarding the version and the type of project your are working on.  My test was done on a winforms project version 4 of the .NET framework.

Comment: I am working on Windows XP home, VS express 2010, framework 4.

Comment: @user1544067 And your building a winforms project right? Perhaps it could be the version of the gdi32.dll file?  Since I am running Windows 7 I might be using a newer version.  I found the gdi32.dll in my C:\Windows\System32 folder, version 6.1.7601.17514, you might want to check yours.  If you wanted to try a new version of this dll then I think you can just add the new file to the application folder (rather than trying to replace the system file).  Better check if you can do this though.

Comment: @user1544067 I have updated my answer with an alternative solution using my own justification method.  This might be a better approach rather than trying to get the gdi32.dll to work (assuming that is what is causing the problems).

Comment: I am building with winforms project.

Comment: I tried to add reference to new Gdi32.dll file in my application, and I found that it is impossible to add a reference to this file. Also to replace the system file is complicated.  But I do not understand why it does not work, my version is 5.1.2600.5512, and this is the appropriate version according to windows XP, and written here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145094(v=vs.85).aspx) that SetTextJustification work from windows 2000?

Comment: The second solution proposed is very wonderful, and I already thought about it use the function drawText for each word separately, and calculate the position of each word, so that the row will be aligned.   The problem is effectively, I checked and found that if I draw each word separately, it takes time X3 than I drawing a line complete.

Comment: The `PaintTextJustification` method certainly could be improved to run a bit faster (and probably improved in other ways too).  I doubt it could be made 3x faster though.