# win32 - with Windows XP Home

Tags: winapi

On MSDN lot win32 functions contain this statement:

Requirements: Minimum supported client - Windows 2000 Professional.

Is it really necessary to use the pro version, or function works with home version.
I use windows-xp home, and I can run many functions, but one function fails without reason, could be that it fails because I do not use pro version?

Comment: Please tell us which function fails

Comment: I'm not asking about the function fails, I am asking about Home version. but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992251/use-function-settextjustification-api)

Comment: @AlexK. That is an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no "*Home*" versions of Windows 2000, *Professional* was the only non-server version released.

If the documentation displays it as the minimum supported version & do not list exceptions for XP, then anything with a minimum of "*Windows 2000 Professional*" will run on XP Home or Pro.